# Java method decrementing values but not reassigning

Tags: java, arrays, list

Okay I got two classes my main which is `Process` and a class called `Scheduler`

Aim: basically create an array of processes, along with their time remaining. Call the schedule class which essentially removes the number 1 from the `timeRemaining`

Here is the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Random rn = new Random();


        Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();

        for(int i = 1; i<=5; i++){
            double rand = rn.nextInt(10);
            Process process = new Process(i,rand);
            scheduler.addObj(process); // adds the object to the array
        }

        scheduler.printQueue(scheduler.getList());
        System.out.println("");
        scheduler.sortQueue(scheduler.getList());
        scheduler.printQueue(scheduler.getList());

        for(int i =0; i <10; i++){
            System.out.println("");
            scheduler.scheduleNext(scheduler.getList());
            scheduler.printQueue(scheduler.getList());
            System.out.println("");
        }  
    }
```

This is creating 5 processes which are stored in an array of objects. I then sort the array by descending order of the time remaining. This works perfectly fine.

The problem is the loop which is from 0 to 10. What i'm trying to make it do is call the method scheduleNext() which chooses which takes the array and then chooses which value to send the schedule method.

This is the scheduleNext() method:

```
public void scheduleNext(ArrayList<Process> list){

        Process firstElement = list.get(0);


        if (firstElement.schedule(firstElement.getTimeRemaining()) == true){
            list.remove(0);
        }
        else{
            Collections.rotate(list,-1);
        }

    }
```

And here is the schedule method :

```
public boolean schedule(double timeRemaining){
        if(timeRemaining < 1){
            this.timeRemaining = 0;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            this.timeRemaining = timeRemaining -1;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I've debugged it through many times, it decrements the timeRemaining and moves it to the bottom of the array. But when I print it out, it just prints out the normal value... Am I reassigning them correct?

**Here's the entire code** (Process Class)

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package process;

import java.util.Random;

/**
 *
 * @author Luke
 */
public class Process implements Comparable<Process> {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    private int processId;
    private double timeRequired;
    private double timeRemaining;

    public Process(int processId, double timeRequired) {
        this.processId = processId;
        this.timeRequired = timeRequired;
        this.timeRemaining = timeRequired;
    }

    public double getTimeRemaining() {
        return timeRemaining;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Random rn = new Random();


        Scheduler scheduler = new Scheduler();

        for(int i = 1; i<=5; i++){
            double rand = rn.nextInt(10);
            Process process = new Process(i,rand);
            scheduler.addObj(process);
        }

        scheduler.printQueue(scheduler.getList());
        System.out.println("");
        scheduler.sortQueue(scheduler.getList());
        scheduler.printQueue(scheduler.getList());

        for(int i =0; i <10; i++){
            System.out.println("");
            scheduler.scheduleNext(scheduler.getList());
            scheduler.printQueue(scheduler.getList());
            System.out.println("");
        }  
    }

     public void setProcessId(int processId) {
        this.processId = processId;
    }

    public void setTimeRequired(double timeRequired) {
        this.timeRequired = timeRequired;
    }

    public int getProcessId() {
        return processId;
    }

    public double getTimeRequired() {
        return timeRequired;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Process o) {
       if (this.timeRequired < o.timeRequired){
           return -1;
       }else if (this.timeRequired > o.timeRequired){
           return 1;
       }else{
           return 0;
       }
    }

    public boolean schedule(double timeRemaining){
        if(timeRemaining < 1){
            this.timeRemaining = 0;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            this.timeRemaining = timeRemaining -1;
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Process{" + "processId=" + processId + ", timeRequired=" + timeRequired + '}';
    }



}
```

(**Scheduler Class**)

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package process;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author Luke
 */
public class Scheduler {

    ArrayList<Process> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public ArrayList<Process> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void addObj(Process p){
        list.add(p);
    }

    public void sortQueue(ArrayList<Process> list){
        Collections.sort(list);
    }

    public void printQueue(ArrayList<Process> list){
        for(Process i: list){
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    public void scheduleNext(ArrayList<Process> list){

        Process firstElement = list.get(0);


        if (firstElement.schedule(firstElement.getTimeRemaining()) == true){
            list.remove(0);
        }
        else{
            Collections.rotate(list,-1);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code works fine. You must have mistaken `timeRequired`, which is printed, for `timeRemaining`, which is decreased.

Comment: You need to inspect the value of `timeRemaining`, so add that to the `toString` method. Something like this: `return "Process{" + "processId=" + processId + ", timeRequired=" + timeRequired + ", timeRemaining=" + timeRemaining + '}';`

Comment: I can't do process.toString() though as the object is only within the forloop right?